# jQuery conflict causing errors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I recently switched from Squarespace to Wordpress. I am currently using the Bridge theme, but this comes with Visual Composer. I don't really like VC, so I tried installing Beaver Builder instead. However, I get some errors in the console when starting the Page Builder. This impact the Page Builder as I cannot use text editor. I can't type text in the text editor & also the icons above the text area frame are not visible.

Below, you can see the errors:

```
"Uncaught Error: no such method 'instance' for menu widget instance" op rij 2 van {bestand}.

Error: no such method 'instance' for menu widget instance
    at Function.error (http://www.petasos.be/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2:1814)
    at HTMLUListElement.<anonymous> (http://www.petasos.be/wp-content/themes/bridge/js/plugins.js?ver=4.7.5:38:8376)
    at Function.each (http://www.petasos.be/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2:2881)
    at a.fn.init.each (http://www.petasos.be/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2:846)
    at a.fn.init.$.fn.(anonymous function) [as menu] (http://www.petasos.be/wp-content/themes/bridge/js/plugins.js?ver=4.7.5:38:8111)
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._create (http://www.petasos.be/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/autocomplete.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11:2191)
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._create (http://www.petasos.be/wp-content/themes/bridge/js/plugins.js?ver=4.7.5:38:6664)
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._createWidget (http://www.petasos.be/wp-content/themes/bridge/js/plugins.js?ver=4.7.5:38:9651)
    at new $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function) (http://www.petasos.be/wp-content/themes/bridge/js/plugins.js?ver=4.7.5:38:5990)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (http://www.petasos.be/wp-content/themes/bridge/js/plugins.js?ver=4.7.5:38:8796)"
```

As the error states there are some issues with my plugins.js & I deactivated this file. Next, Beaver Builder works. But when I disable this file, a lot of JS effects on the website do no longer function.

Does anyone have experience with this kind of error? I think it is related to a jQuery version conflict, but I am not sure? If you need more information, ask & I'll provide.

### Update after installing jQuery plugin:

Below, installing the jQuery plugin was suggested. Error messages in the console have changed, but still having the issue with the text editor.

```
Error: no such method 'instance' for menu widget instance
    at Function.error (http://www.petasos.be/wp-content/plugins/jquery-updater/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js?ver=3.2.1:2:1979)
    at HTMLUListElement.<anonymous> (http://www.petasos.be/wp-content/themes/bridge/js/plugins.js?ver=4.7.5:38:8376)
    at Function.each (http://www.petasos.be/wp-content/plugins/jquery-updater/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js?ver=3.2.1:2:2715)
    at a.fn.init.each (http://www.petasos.be/wp-content/plugins/jquery-updater/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js?ver=3.2.1:2:1003)
    at a.fn.init.$.fn.(anonymous function) [as menu] (http://www.petasos.be/wp-content/themes/bridge/js/plugins.js?ver=4.7.5:38:8111)
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._create (http://www.petasos.be/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/autocomplete.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11:2191)
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._create (http://www.petasos.be/wp-content/themes/bridge/js/plugins.js?ver=4.7.5:38:6664)
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._createWidget (http://www.petasos.be/wp-content/themes/bridge/js/plugins.js?ver=4.7.5:38:9651)
    at new $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function) (http://www.petasos.be/wp-content/themes/bridge/js/plugins.js?ver=4.7.5:38:5990)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (http://www.petasos.be/wp-content/themes/bridge/js/plugins.js?ver=4.7.5:38:8796)
```

Answer (score 0):

WordPress automatically calls the core jQuery, which [may not be the most recent version](https://plugins.twinpictures.de/wordpress-jquery-versions/). You could try running [jQuery Updater](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-updater/) and see if this pertains to the jQuery version.

Another thing to look for is if more than one jQuery script is being called on the page - an easy way to check is to simply export the page as static HTML and search for any duplicate/redundant calls of the script.

Comment: you can also check `sources/network/application` panels under Inspector for `scripts loaded`/ `find duplicate scripts`.

Comment: Okay Sambgordon, most helpful! Will check this right away. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, a lot of scripts loaded, but only 1 jQuery it seems? http://i.imgur.com/rCHoE26.png